# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Amazon EC2 instance with node.js backend

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, node.js, godaddy

I have a website running in Elatic Beanstalk. In default-environment [url](http://default-environment.jxqppvgmkn.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/), it is working totally fine. But, when I try to access it with my domain from GoDaddy it is showing `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I have properly set nameservers and ip on godaddy as per godaddy tech assistance. 
In security groups, server is listening on port 80. I my node `server.js`, I have set this.

```
app.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000,function(req,res){
  console.log("Express Server is Running ......");
});
```

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: make sure that you are editing correct EC2 secuirty group. Go to the EC2 instance and check which security group is attached to it

Comment: yes, launch-wizard-1 is the security group attached to it.

Comment: My elastic beanstalk environment shows a different security group.However, that security group also has port 80 open in it.

Comment: Have you Cnamed your domain name?. can we see your domain details?.

Comment: You need to add a CNAME record for your domai name to default-environment.jxqppvgmkn.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

Comment: Ok, I have added CNAME. I guess it takes some time get updated. I have also contacted godaddy. They said to wait for 15 mins for it to get updated.